# FetchError: request failed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, fetch, absolute-path

I have a bug, i'm trying to make his tutorial for twitter clone in nextjs+tailwindcss+typescript

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCselwxbUgA&t=1357s&ab_channel=SonnySangha
1:42:05 / 3:17:52

I did exactly the same but i feel like my IDE or my nextJS version is making things different

```
import { Tweet } from "../typings"

export const fetchTweets = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/getTweets/`)
    const data = await res.json();
    const tweets: Tweet[] = data.tweets;
    return tweets
}
```

> FetchError: request to https://localhost:3000/api/getTweets/ failed,
> reason: write EPROTO 140020696905664:error:1408F10B:SSL
> routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version
> number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs  >will be displayed in the terminal window.

```
import { Tweet } from "../typings"  
  
export const fetchTweets = async () => {  
      
    if(global.window) {  
        const res = await 
        fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/getTweets/`)  
        const data = await res.json();  
        const tweets: Tweet[] = data.tweets;  
        return tweets  
    }  
      
}
```

> Server Error Error: Error serializing `.tweets` returned from
> `getServerSideProps` in "/". Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized
> as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.

If someone can help me <3 thanks

Comment: i did tell me if this is clear enough

Comment: Seems like your API endpoints aren't returning what you think they are. May want to check your URLs and their responses.

Comment: NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=https://localhost:3000/

Comment: const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/getTweets/`) is the same as

Comment: const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/getTweets/`)

Comment: No one can check what your localhost is returning -- that's up to you to do.

Comment: but the last one work i just wanna understand why it doesnt respond right with `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/getTweets/` it seems the same

Comment: You don't have a scheme (like `http`) in `NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL`. So, they aren't the same.

Comment: i have this is just hidden in comments idk why

Comment: nvm i did it thx <3

Answer (score 1):

FIXED :

.env.local

i writed

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=https://localhost:3000/
```

change **https://** by **http://** and **yarn run dev** again

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/
```